# Difference between creating cluster-aware service and Windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-server-2008, cluster-computing

I want to create 2 cluster-aware services for running on 2 Windows server2008 systems.

I could write simple code for Windows service, but couldn't find anything to show me how to develop a service for cluster.

could anyone provide a sample code that show this steps?